# Selenium findElement by CSS and sending form

Tags: javascript, css, selenium

I'am new in selenium and have some question about my first script.

```
driver.findElement({ css: '.input[name=login]' }).sendKeys('login');
//driver.sleep(0);
driver.findElement({ css: '.input.passwd' }).sendKeys('passwd');
driver.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement({ css: '.button[type=submit]' }).click();                        
driver.sleep(10000);
driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log(title);
    assert.ok(title.indexOf('Title') > -1, 'Wrong title');
}
```

And after executing i still on the login page and don't have errors except "AssertionError: Wrong title".
If selenium doesn't find some element i have an error like "NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:",
so i think all elements was found and all actions like "sendKeys" and "click" worked. But it didn't. 
How can i check it, during execution script? 
How can i see, what query selenium generated and sent to the server?

UPD:

```
<input name="login" value="" type="text" class="input" tabindex="5">
<input name="" value="" type="password" class="input passwd" tabindex="6">
<input hidefocus="true" type="submit" class="button"></input>
```

Comment: `driver.getTitle()` returns string, check what it returns.

Comment: It returns title from Login page, not title from inner page.

Comment: I meant that you should check if the title it returns does contains 'Title' with capital latter.

Comment: The error is in the compression.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand... in what compression?

Comment: In `assert.ok`. The `assert` can't find `'Title'` in the page title.

Comment: Sorry, I had typo. I meant comparison.

Comment: I know it, it cant find "Title" because something  in previous code doesn't work, so authorization doesn't work and i want to know, how can i debug this problem...

Comment: Can you add the html of the login form?

Comment: I updated main post.

Answer (score 0):

You used class attribute as html tag. For example `class=input` and `name=login` are both attributes of the WebElement of `<input>` tag. Try

```
driver.findElement({ css: 'input[name="login"]' }).sendKeys('login');
driver.findElement({ css: '.passwd' }).sendKeys('passwd');
driver.findElement({ css: '.button' }).click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement({ name: 'login' }).sendKeys('login');
driver.findElement({ className: 'passwd' }).sendKeys('passwd');
driver.findElement({ className: 'button' }).click();
```

Or using By class

```
driver.findElement(By.name('login')).sendKeys('login');
driver.findElement(By.className('passwd')).sendKeys('passwd');
driver.findElement(By.className('button')).click();
```